# Kentico 7 invalid logon attempts

Tags: kentico

According to the docs I can control the number of logon attempts using Settings -> Security & Membership -> Protection --> Invalid logon attempts but whatever value I put in here the user is always locked out after 5 attempts. Is there another setting that may be controlling this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the settings - select your site from the dropdown list and set the value for your site.

Or change a global value and check "Inherit from global settings" on the site level.